# ESP32-C3 External Flash

Tags: esp32

I designed a custom PCB with ESP32-C3 with external flash, I used W25Q128JVSIQ but when I am trying to flash it is throwing this error **A fatal error occurred: Packet content transfer stopped (received 8 bytes)**. I connected the flash to default pins as shown in the picture.

[image: Schematics]

Here is what I am getting on flash

```
Serial port COM26
Connecting...    
Chip is ESP32-C3 (QFN32) (revision v0.4)
Features: WiFi, BLE
Crystal is 40MHz   
MAC: 48:31:b7:35:8b:9c
Uploading stub...     
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 460800
Changed.
Configuring flash size...
Warning: Could not auto-detect Flash size (FlashID=0xffff03, SizeID=0xff), defaulting to 4MB
Flash will be erased from 0x00000000 to 0x00005fff...
Flash will be erased from 0x00010000 to 0x0003efff...
Flash will be erased from 0x00008000 to 0x00008fff...
Flash params set to 0x022f
Compressed 20496 bytes to 12566...

A fatal error occurred: Packet content transfer stopped (received 8 bytes)
```

eFuse Dump

```
espefuse.py v4.7.dev2
Connecting...
Detecting chip type... ESP32-C3
BLOCK0          (                ) [0 ] read_regs: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 80000000 00000000
MAC_SPI_8M_0    (BLOCK1          ) [1 ] read_regs: b7358b9c 00004831 00000000 03100000 41d1c340 00070a90
BLOCK_SYS_DATA  (BLOCK2          ) [2 ] read_regs: b5bbfdf0 d4d4d60f 7947a468 9d497ef2 97b4ca29 ca762483 a6498624 00000009
BLOCK_USR_DATA  (BLOCK3          ) [3 ] read_regs: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
BLOCK_KEY0      (BLOCK4          ) [4 ] read_regs: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
BLOCK_KEY1      (BLOCK5          ) [5 ] read_regs: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
BLOCK_KEY2      (BLOCK6          ) [6 ] read_regs: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
BLOCK_KEY3      (BLOCK7          ) [7 ] read_regs: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
BLOCK_KEY4      (BLOCK8          ) [8 ] read_regs: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
BLOCK_KEY5      (BLOCK9          ) [9 ] read_regs: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
BLOCK_SYS_DATA2 (BLOCK10         ) [10] read_regs: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

BLOCK0          (                ) [0 ] err__regs: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
EFUSE_RD_RS_ERR0_REG        0x00000000
EFUSE_RD_RS_ERR1_REG        0x00000000
```

eFuse Summery

```
espefuse.py v4.7.dev2
Connecting...
Detecting chip type... ESP32-C3

=== Run "summary" command ===
EFUSE_NAME (Block) Description  = [Meaningful Value] [Readable/Writeable] (Hex Value)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Calibration fuses:
K_RTC_LDO (BLOCK1)                                 BLOCK1 K_RTC_LDO                                   = 24 R/W (0b0000110)
K_DIG_LDO (BLOCK1)                                 BLOCK1 K_DIG_LDO                                   = -28 R/W (0b1000111)
V_RTC_DBIAS20 (BLOCK1)                             BLOCK1 voltage of rtc dbias20                      = 56 R/W (0x0e)
V_DIG_DBIAS20 (BLOCK1)                             BLOCK1 voltage of digital dbias20                  = -8 R/W (0x82)
DIG_DBIAS_HVT (BLOCK1)                             BLOCK1 digital dbias when hvt                      = -16 R/W (0b10100)
THRES_HVT (BLOCK1)                                 BLOCK1 pvt threshold when hvt                      = 1800 R/W (0b0111000010)
TEMP_CALIB (BLOCK2)                                Temperature calibration data                       = -6.9 R/W (0b101000101)
OCODE (BLOCK2)                                     ADC OCode                                          = 76 R/W (0x4c)
ADC1_INIT_CODE_ATTEN0 (BLOCK2)                     ADC1 init code at atten0                           = 1516 R/W (0b0101111011)
ADC1_INIT_CODE_ATTEN1 (BLOCK2)                     ADC1 init code at atten1                           = -56 R/W (0b1000001110)
ADC1_INIT_CODE_ATTEN2 (BLOCK2)                     ADC1 init code at atten2                           = -144 R/W (0b1000100100)
ADC1_INIT_CODE_ATTEN3 (BLOCK2)                     ADC1 init code at atten3                           = -628 R/W (0b1010011101)
ADC1_CAL_VOL_ATTEN0 (BLOCK2)                       ADC1 calibration voltage at atten0                 = -304 R/W (0b1001001100)
ADC1_CAL_VOL_ATTEN1 (BLOCK2)                       ADC1 calibration voltage at atten1                 = -96 R/W (0b1000011000)
ADC1_CAL_VOL_ATTEN2 (BLOCK2)                       ADC1 calibration voltage at atten2                 = -292 R/W (0b1001001001)
ADC1_CAL_VOL_ATTEN3 (BLOCK2)                       ADC1 calibration voltage at atten3                 = -420 R/W (0b1001101001)

Config fuses:
WR_DIS (BLOCK0)                                    Disable programming of individual eFuses           = 0 R/W (0x00000000)
RD_DIS (BLOCK0)                                    Disable reading from BlOCK4-10                     = 0 R/W (0b0000000)
DIS_ICACHE (BLOCK0)                                Set this bit to disable Icache                     = False R/W (0b0)
DIS_TWAI (BLOCK0)                                  Set this bit to disable CAN function               = False R/W (0b0)
DIS_DIRECT_BOOT (BLOCK0)                           Disable direct boot mode                           = False R/W (0b0)
UART_PRINT_CONTROL (BLOCK0)                        Set the default UARTboot message output mode       = Enable R/W (0b00)
ERR_RST_ENABLE (BLOCK0)                            Use BLOCK0 to check error record registers         = with check R/W (0b1)
BLOCK_USR_DATA (BLOCK3)                            User data
   = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 R/W
BLOCK_SYS_DATA2 (BLOCK10)                          System data part 2 (reserved)
   = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 R/W

Flash fuses:
FLASH_TPUW (BLOCK0)                                Configures flash waiting time after power-up; in u = 0 R/W (0x0)
                                                   nit of ms. If the value is less than 15; the waiti
                                                   ng time is the configurable value; Otherwise; the
                                                   waiting time is twice the configurable value
FORCE_SEND_RESUME (BLOCK0)                         Set this bit to force ROM code to send a resume co = False R/W (0b0)
                                                   mmand during SPI boot
FLASH_CAP (BLOCK1)                                 Flash capacity                                     = None R/W (0b000)
FLASH_TEMP (BLOCK1)                                Flash temperature                                  = None R/W (0b00)
FLASH_VENDOR (BLOCK1)                              Flash vendor                                       = None R/W (0b000)

Identity fuses:
DISABLE_WAFER_VERSION_MAJOR (BLOCK0)               Disables check of wafer version major              = False R/W (0b0)
DISABLE_BLK_VERSION_MAJOR (BLOCK0)                 Disables check of blk version major                = False R/W (0b0)
WAFER_VERSION_MINOR_LO (BLOCK1)                    WAFER_VERSION_MINOR least significant bits         = 4 R/W (0b100)
PKG_VERSION (BLOCK1)                               Package version                                    = 0 R/W (0b000)
BLK_VERSION_MINOR (BLOCK1)                         BLK_VERSION_MINOR                                  = 3 R/W (0b011)
WAFER_VERSION_MINOR_HI (BLOCK1)                    WAFER_VERSION_MINOR most significant bit           = False R/W (0b0)
WAFER_VERSION_MAJOR (BLOCK1)                       WAFER_VERSION_MAJOR                                = 0 R/W (0b00)
OPTIONAL_UNIQUE_ID (BLOCK2)                        Optional unique 128-bit ID
   = f0 fd bb b5 0f d6 d4 d4 68 a4 47 79 f2 7e 49 9d R/W
BLK_VERSION_MAJOR (BLOCK2)                         BLK_VERSION_MAJOR of BLOCK2                        = With calibration R/W (0b01)
WAFER_VERSION_MINOR (BLOCK0)                       calc WAFER VERSION MINOR = WAFER_VERSION_MINOR_HI  = 4 R/W (0x4)
                                                   << 3 + WAFER_VERSION_MINOR_LO (read only)

Jtag fuses:
SOFT_DIS_JTAG (BLOCK0)                             Set these bits to disable JTAG in the soft way (od = 0 R/W (0b000)
                                                   d number 1 means disable ). JTAG can be enabled in
                                                    HMAC module
DIS_PAD_JTAG (BLOCK0)                              Set this bit to disable JTAG in the hard way. JTAG = False R/W (0b0)
                                                    is disabled permanently

Mac fuses:
MAC (BLOCK1)                                       MAC address
   = 48:31:b7:35:8b:9c (OK) R/W
CUSTOM_MAC (BLOCK3)                                Custom MAC address
   = 00:00:00:00:00:00 (OK) R/W

Security fuses:
DIS_DOWNLOAD_ICACHE (BLOCK0)                       Set this bit to disable Icache in download mode (b = False R/W (0b0)
                                                   oot_mode[3:0] is 0; 1; 2; 3; 6; 7)
DIS_FORCE_DOWNLOAD (BLOCK0)                        Set this bit to disable the function that forces c = False R/W (0b0)
                                                   hip into download mode
DIS_DOWNLOAD_MANUAL_ENCRYPT (BLOCK0)               Set this bit to disable flash encryption when in d = False R/W (0b0)
                                                   ownload boot modes
SPI_BOOT_CRYPT_CNT (BLOCK0)                        Enables flash encryption when 1 or 3 bits are set  = Disable R/W (0b000)
                                                   and disables otherwise
SECURE_BOOT_KEY_REVOKE0 (BLOCK0)                   Revoke 1st secure boot key                         = False R/W (0b0)
SECURE_BOOT_KEY_REVOKE1 (BLOCK0)                   Revoke 2nd secure boot key                         = False R/W (0b0)
SECURE_BOOT_KEY_REVOKE2 (BLOCK0)                   Revoke 3rd secure boot key                         = False R/W (0b0)
KEY_PURPOSE_0 (BLOCK0)                             Purpose of Key0                                    = USER R/W (0x0)
KEY_PURPOSE_1 (BLOCK0)                             Purpose of Key1                                    = USER R/W (0x0)
KEY_PURPOSE_2 (BLOCK0)                             Purpose of Key2                                    = USER R/W (0x0)
KEY_PURPOSE_3 (BLOCK0)                             Purpose of Key3                                    = USER R/W (0x0)
KEY_PURPOSE_4 (BLOCK0)                             Purpose of Key4                                    = USER R/W (0x0)
KEY_PURPOSE_5 (BLOCK0)                             Purpose of Key5                                    = USER R/W (0x0)
SECURE_BOOT_EN (BLOCK0)                            Set this bit to enable secure boot                 = False R/W (0b0)
SECURE_BOOT_AGGRESSIVE_REVOKE (BLOCK0)             Set this bit to enable revoking aggressive secure  = False R/W (0b0)
                                                   boot
DIS_DOWNLOAD_MODE (BLOCK0)                         Set this bit to disable download mode (boot_mode[3 = False R/W (0b0)
                                                   :0] = 0; 1; 2; 3; 6; 7)
ENABLE_SECURITY_DOWNLOAD (BLOCK0)                  Set this bit to enable secure UART download mode   = False R/W (0b0)
SECURE_VERSION (BLOCK0)                            Secure version (used by ESP-IDF anti-rollback feat = 0 R/W (0x0000)
                                                   ure)
BLOCK_KEY0 (BLOCK4)
  Purpose: USER
               Key0 or user data
   = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 R/W
BLOCK_KEY1 (BLOCK5)
  Purpose: USER
               Key1 or user data
   = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 R/W
BLOCK_KEY2 (BLOCK6)
  Purpose: USER
               Key2 or user data
   = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 R/W
BLOCK_KEY3 (BLOCK7)
  Purpose: USER
               Key3 or user data
   = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 R/W
BLOCK_KEY4 (BLOCK8)
  Purpose: USER
               Key4 or user data
   = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 R/W
BLOCK_KEY5 (BLOCK9)
  Purpose: USER
               Key5 or user data
   = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 R/W

Spi Pad fuses:
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_CLK (BLOCK1)                        SPI PAD CLK                                        = 0 R/W (0b000000)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_Q (BLOCK1)                          SPI PAD Q(D1)                                      = 0 R/W (0b000000)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_D (BLOCK1)                          SPI PAD D(D0)                                      = 0 R/W (0b000000)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_CS (BLOCK1)                         SPI PAD CS                                         = 0 R/W (0b000000)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_HD (BLOCK1)                         SPI PAD HD(D3)                                     = 0 R/W (0b000000)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_WP (BLOCK1)                         SPI PAD WP(D2)                                     = 0 R/W (0b000000)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_DQS (BLOCK1)                        SPI PAD DQS                                        = 0 R/W (0b000000)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_D4 (BLOCK1)                         SPI PAD D4                                         = 0 R/W (0b000000)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_D5 (BLOCK1)                         SPI PAD D5                                         = 0 R/W (0b000000)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_D6 (BLOCK1)                         SPI PAD D6                                         = 0 R/W (0b000000)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_D7 (BLOCK1)                         SPI PAD D7                                         = 0 R/W (0b000000)

Usb fuses:
DIS_USB_JTAG (BLOCK0)                              Set this bit to disable function of usb switch to  = False R/W (0b0)
                                                   jtag in module of usb device
DIS_USB_SERIAL_JTAG (BLOCK0)                       USB-Serial-JTAG                                    = Enable R/W (0b0)
USB_EXCHG_PINS (BLOCK0)                            Set this bit to exchange USB D+ and D- pins        = False R/W (0b0)
DIS_USB_SERIAL_JTAG_ROM_PRINT (BLOCK0)             USB printing                                       = Enable R/W (0b0)
DIS_USB_SERIAL_JTAG_DOWNLOAD_MODE (BLOCK0)         Disable UART download mode through USB-Serial-JTAG = False R/W (0b0)
Vdd fuses:
VDD_SPI_AS_GPIO (BLOCK0)                           Set this bit to vdd spi pin function as gpio       = False R/W (0b0)

Wdt fuses:
WDT_DELAY_SEL (BLOCK0)                             RTC watchdog timeout threshold; in unit of slow cl = 40000 R/W (0b00)
                                                   ock cycle
```

Comment: Why do you have 100R resistors in series with all of the SPI signals to the external flash?

Comment: I used the ESP32-C3 Wroom as reference design. https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-c3-wroom-02_datasheet_en.pdf

Comment: The reference design does not have a 100ohm resistor on SPICS0 line.

Comment: I shorted all the Flash lines removing 100R. It is working now. Thanks @hcheung. I always over looked it